# How to create a multiple-names-method?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have some URL like this:

```
www.example.com/classname/method1/arg
www.example.com/classname/method2/arg
www.example.com/classname/method3/arg
```

Also I have a `class` like this:

```
class classname{

    public function method1($arg){
        return $this->main_method(__FUNCTION__, $arg);
    }

    public function method2($arg){
        return $this->main_method(__FUNCTION__, $arg);
    }

    public function method3($arg){
        return $this->main_method(__FUNCTION__, $arg);
    }

    public main_method($TableName, $arg){
        // connect to database
        $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT id, word, mean FROM $TableName where word = ':word'");
        $stm->bindValue(":word", $arg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->execute();
        $result = $stm->fetch();

        return = $result;
    }
}
```

As is clear from the above code, there is three tables:

```
// method1                    // method2                    // method3
+----+------+-----------+     +----+------+-----------+     +----+------+-----------+
| id | word |   mean    |     | id | word |   mean    |     | id | word |   mean    |
+----+------+-----------+     +----+------+-----------+     +----+------+-----------+
```

---

Now I want to know, is it possible to I create just one function with multiple names? Because those three methods have a *(almost*) identical operation... *(and I can pass the name of method as another argument to that multiple-names method)* Or how can I optimize the above code?

Comment: Either I'm missing the point, or you're just trying to do something meaningless. All your parameters are the same. The function finally does only one task. Why can't you just use one function/method?

Comment: How are the operations of each method different?

Comment: @itsols `__FUNCTION__` is different in each method.

Comment: @itsols btw, I cannot use one method because there is three separated tables and each method searches in one of them.

Comment: Please include in your question the outline (algorithm) of each function you're passing as parameter

Comment: Well, I don't know what you need exactly that I include it. Look, there is three separated tables in the database *(same structure)*, each method search in one of those tables *(according to the name of method)*, Now, the above algorithm is fine? Or is there a better algorithm for doing that?

Comment: Your approach is fine. BTW, I believe the `main_method()` doesn't need to be `public`, and I also believe you've missed the `function` keyword in its declaration and the `=` in the `return` statement is a syntax error!

Comment: Just use one table with an extra field called 'method' and remove the others...

Answer (score 1):

So You have three tables in DB with exactly the same columns?
You should keep everything in one table with one API method and one executive method.

Comment: Good point ..! I thought about it already ..! Yeah agreed ..! But I think searching in one small table will be faster than one huge table ..!

Comment: It is easier to manage one table especially if you use relationships. If You set the indexes properly You will not have to ever worry about performance.